# Changing content of a Label with a DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

I try to change the behaviour of my labels to show a '-' whenever they would usually display a '0'. I tried to achieve this by using a DataTrigger (I was also thinking about a converter but a DataTrigger would be probably the more elegant solution for my code).

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding LsMw, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:########0}">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="-"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
```

Unfortunately neither this nor a varaint where I bind the trigger directly to the property works.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that if you set `Content` via an attribute, the Style is unable to replace the value of Content (due to [dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence)). If you set the default Content Binding via a Style Setter instead of an attribute, the trigger would be able to replace that, because the Style is allowed to override itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use a `TextBlock`, or set the `Content` of the `Label` to a `TextBlock`, you could use:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LsMw, StringFormat={}{0:########0;-########0;-}}"/>
```